# retain the newline in a regex Match, c#

Tags: c#, regex

So, i've created the following regex which captures everything i need from my string:

```
  const string tag = ":59";
  var result = Regex.Split(message, String.Format(":{0}[^:]?:*[^:]*", tag),RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

the string follows this patter:

```
:59A:/sometext\n
somemore text\n
:71A:somemore text
```

I'm trying to capture everything in between :59A: and :71A: - this isn't fixed in stone though, as :71A: could be something else. hence, why i was using [^:]

***EDIT***

So, just to be clear on my requirements. I have a file(string) which is passed into a C# method, which should return only those values specified in the parameter tag. For instance, if the file(string) contains the following tags:

:20:
:21:
:59A:
:71A:

and i pass in 59 then i only need to return everything in between the start of tag :59A: and the start of the next tag, which in this instance is :71A:, but could be something else.

Comment: What is the exact pattern for your delimiters?

Comment: newline is the delimiter :something: is the start of new tag

Comment: Can you provide the output you want from the input string in your question?

Comment: Are you aware how redundant this is `:{0}` ? I think you want something like [`:[^:]+:([^:]+)`](http://regex101.com/r/tO5dI2)

Comment: ok, so i need /sometext\nsomemore text\n FYI there are infinite \n between :59a: and :71A:

Comment: HamZa, this is a c# placeholder, for the variable tag

Comment: @CSharpNewBee Facepalm, my bad. Then you've got `::59` in the pattern. No wonder it won't match. Try to use the pattern I provided above. Also please ping me by using `@` otherwise I won't receive a notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to match what you need:

```
string input = ":59A:/sometext\nsomemore text\n:71A:somemore text";
string pattern = "(?<=:[^:]+:)[^:]+\n";

var m = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline).Value;
```

If you want to use your tag constant, you can use this code

```
const string tag = ":59";
string input = ":59A:/sometext\nsomemore text\n:71A:somemore text";
string pattern = String.Format("(?<={0}[^:]*:)[^:]+\n", tag);

var m = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline).Value;
```

Comment: not sure this addresses the param tag I have. the file contains multiple tags. I pas in 59 into the tag param, and need to loop through the string (example above is an trimmed version) and then only perform the reg match on the specified tag name. I'll make some amends to the original post to make this cleaer

Comment: @CSharpNewBee Added a version with the tag constant.

Comment: wonderful Szymon all i need to do now is convert this to a List<string> cheers