# Match a string, including newline, between two delimiters using Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to match a string contained within two delimiters << and >> as follows:

```
Today is a <<beautiful day. \n How are you doing today?>>
```

How can I match anything between the delimiters, regardless of special characters? I want to get: `beautiful day. \n How are you doing today?`

This is what I have so far: `<<(.*?)>>`

Comment: You can make the dot match a newline with `(?s)<<(.*?)>>`

Comment: Or use `RegexOptions.Singleline`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [retain the newline in a regex Match, c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22347795/retain-the-newline-in-a-regex-match-c-sharp)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22347795/retain-the-newline-in-a-regex-match-c-sharp

Comment: ...or use a positive lookbehind and a positive lookahead to match without a capture group: `(?s)(?<=<<).*?(?=>>)`.

Comment: @The fourth bird, you comment worked, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
<<([\s\S]*?)>>
```

This should match opening `<<` delimiters followed by zero or more occurrences of any whitespace or non-whitespace characters and closing delimiter `>>`